# Linear time complexity

Tags: complexity-theory

We know from the linear-speedup-theorem that

NTIME($\mathcal{O}(f)$) = NTIME($f$) and DTIME($\mathcal{O}(f)$) = DTIME($f$),

given that $f(n) > (1+\varepsilon) n$ for some $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$.

What happens in the case that $f(n)=n$?

I was told that equality still holds in the nondeterministic case, but not in the deterministic case.

But I cannot find a proof for the former or a counter-example for the latter equality.

Can anyone provide either (or preferably both)? Thank you!